Chakra-UI V3 - Problems to run tests - Cannot find module '@ark-ui/react/format'
I recently started this project and I am trying to use the new version of Chakra UI V3. Honestly, I can't run any tests. None, only when I remove the Chakra-UI provider (and remove the other things that use chakra-ui). I don't know what I might be configuring wrong, so I will leave all the possible files. I will put just App.tsx because is the same error for the components too.
I don't know more what to do :(
Error:
 FAIL  src/App.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@ark-ui/react/format' from 'node_modules/@chakra-ui/react/dist/cjs/components/format/index.cjs'

    Require stack:
      node_modules/@chakra-ui/react/dist/cjs/components/format/index.cjs
      node_modules/@chakra-ui/react/dist/cjs/index.cjs
      src/components/ui/provider.tsx
      src/App.tsx
      src/App.test.tsx

      1 | "use client"
      2 |
    > 3 | import { ChakraProvider, defaultSystem } from "@chakra-ui/react"
        | ^
      4 | import {
      5 |   ColorModeProvider,
      6 |   type ColorModeProviderProps,

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:324:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@chakra-ui/react/dist/cjs/components/format/index.cjs:4:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@chakra-ui/react/dist/cjs/index.cjs:4:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/ui/provider.tsx:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.tsx:4:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.tsx:3:1)


app.tsx
import React from "react";

import "./App.css";
import { Provider } from "./components/ui/provider";
import BooksProvider from "./contexts/booksContext";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Header from "./components/Header";

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider defaultTheme="light">
      <BooksProvider>
        <Header />
        <Home />
      </BooksProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;


app.test.tsx: Here I tried to pass the provider as a parameter to the wrapper of the render, nothing. I'll leave the provider file below, but it comes in the new version with snippets from Chakra-UI V3.
I tried use , same.

import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "./components/ui/provider";

test("renders learn react link", () => {
  render(
    <Provider>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});


**components/ui/provider.tsx (snippet generate by chakra)
**
"use client"

import { ChakraProvider, defaultSystem } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import {
  ColorModeProvider,
  type ColorModeProviderProps,
} from "./color-mode"

export function Provider(props: ColorModeProviderProps) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider value={defaultSystem}>
      <ColorModeProvider {...props} />
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
}

package.json
{
  "name": "best-sellers-books-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ark-ui/react": "^4.3.0",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "3.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.13.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "next-themes": "^0.4.3",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-icons": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
}

Tried to pass the provider as a parameter to the wrapper of the render, nothing. I'll leave the provider file below, but it comes in the new version with snippets from Chakra-UI V3. I tried use , same. I tried use , same. On the files tests.
Thanks :)

I solved it by adding this code to moduleNameMapper in jest.config:
"^@ark-ui/react/(.*)$": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/@ark-ui/react/dist/components/$1/index.cjs",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/@ark-ui/react/dist/components/$1.cjs",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/@ark-ui/react/dist/providers/$1/index.cjs",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/@ark-ui/react/dist/providers/$1.cjs",
],

